# Flask : session not working. Showing session object has no attribute 'modified'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-session

I'm trying to pass a list of dictionaries between Flask pages through session 
but it is giving me this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNUux.png)

I have an **__init__.py** file inside a package `flaskapp` that imports all the modules I created and runs `app = Flask(__name__)`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from flaskapp import api_views
from flaskapp import admin_views
from flaskapp import utilities
from flaskapp import firebase_admin_views
```

and doing this inside my **admin_views.py**

```
from flask import session
from flaskapp import app

app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = 'secret key'
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = 'filesystem'

@app.route('/get/result',methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_result():
    '''
        Code to process my data
    '''
    session['DICT_DATA'] = dict_data

@app.route('/get/result/download',methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_result():
    dict_data = session['DICT_DATA']
```

Can anyone please tell me why is this happening

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was using `"` (double quotes) instead of `'` (single quote) in `session["DICT_DATA"] = dict_data`

You should be using **'** (Single quote) to create session.

Answer (score 0):

So your `app.config` settings should be in the same file as `app = Flask(__name__)`. Then remove `from flaskapp import app`